# Spring ModelAndView not rendering the returned view

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, post, modelandview

I am having a problem with springs ModelAndView. I am making a post call from a form, and all i want is to render a new page after that post. This should not be a difficult task but i cannot seem to do it! So here is my code:

```
   //controller logic
   String viewName = "pages/products/product";
   modelAndView = new ModelAndView( viewName, model );

   return modelAndView;
```

I do not get any exceptions, and i know that the code is working because the response that comes after the post is html code that needs to be rendered, but it is not rendered.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How are you submitting your form? Is it an ajax call or are you using a "submit" button?

Comment: I didn`t explain that part, sorry. I have a javascript dialog window that pops up with the form fields and the form contains a submit button that submits the form data.

Comment: Since the response is ok (according to your post), my guess is that your problem is not  Spring related: please post the relevant html/javascript part responsible for submitting the form.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was that i oversaw that the post call was made with an AJAX call, and i added javscript window.location to point to right redirect URL! Thanks for the help!